# Linq Extension query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Model:

```
Party:
 PartyID
 Partyname

Entitlement:
 EntitlementID
 PartyID
 ClaimValueID

ClaimValue:
 ClaimValueID
 ClaimValue

UserEntitlement:
 UserID
 EntitlementID

User:
 UserID
 UserName
```

Partys are assigned Entitlements. Entitlements can be granted to users.

One of the Entitlements that a party is granted has a claimvalue of "Administrator"

I need to find all the users who have a particular user as their Administrator.

eg.

Users holds 3 users:
Bob, Terry and June

Bob holds the "Administrator" entitlement for "party 1" and "party 2"

Terry holds the "user" entitlement for "party 1" and "party 3"

June holds the "user entitlement for "party 3"

I would expect the resulting collection to hold Bob and Terry only.

I have tried a number of different Linq extension queries but I'm not sure I fully understand my Selects, includes, etc.

I have tried the following, plus many other combinations which i no longer have.

```
var usersA = db.UserEntitlements.Where(a => a.Entitlement.ClaimValue.Value == "Administrator" && a.UserID == 1)
   .Select(b => b.Entitlement.Party)
   .SelectMany(a => a.Entitlements)
   .Include(b => b.UserEntitlements)
   .SelectMany(a => a.UserEntitlements)
   .Include(b => b.User);
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Entity Framework I presume?

Comment: What is the result of the code sample?

Comment: It returns the current user only, so in the example Bob.

Yes Entityframework.

Comment: Yes, Bob us user id 1.

Comment: So Terry is missing from the result. The code looks like it should work, are you sure the state in the DB is like you described it? Can you validate that?

Comment: Unless I'm being super dim, shouldn't you have stopped typing after the first `Select()`...?  Aren't *Parties* the subject of entitlements, whereas *Users* have Entitlements.  Or am I mixed up?

Comment: I guess I haven't explained it too well. The first select will give me the Partys, but what I need is the users who have access to those parties.

Comment: The query is - give me all the users in parties where Bob is the admin. It's pretty hard to read but the code does just that...

Comment: So this query gives me users
`var usersg = db.UserEntitlements.Where(a => a.Entitlement.ClaimValue.Value == "Administrator" && a.UserID == 1)
               .Select(b => b.Entitlement.Party)
               .SelectMany(a => a.Entitlements)
               .Include(b => b.UserEntitlements)
               .SelectMany(a => a.UserEntitlements)
               .Include(b => b.User)
               .Select(u => u.User).ToList();`

but it gives me just Bob.

Comment: Have you re-validated the database state?

Comment: @Jamie: so, you want all the users who are admins of all the parties that Bob is an admin of??

Comment: Hold on, using the OP try making your last `Include` into a `Select`.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner - Thats what I did in my last comment. It just returns Bob (user id 1) twice.

Comment: @Jamie sorry, I can't read multiple lines in comments that well. :-) Not sure that it would cause your issue, but, `SelectMany(a => a.UserEntitlements)` doesn't need to be a `SelectMany` does it?  Isn't `Entitlement` to `UserEntitlement` a 1 to 1 relationship?  I'd also drop the includes for now, just to get it working.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner You can have an Entitlement like `{id=1,claimvalue="user",partyid=3` with multiple `UserEntitlement` referencing that Entitlement. That would mean these users are "user" in party 3.

Comment: @MotiAzu OK.  I'm starting to think it should just bloody work.!

Comment: I took some timeout and worked on a different bit of the solution and have come back to this now. I don't know what I have changed or if I had spent too long looking at it but it does work.
Thanks for the help!!! How do I mark a winner here?

Answer (score 0):

When you have graphs entity framework stops at the first many to many relation otherwise it will return the complete DB. you need to split it in two queries.

Comment: Could you provide some links to this information? I didn't quite get it

Comment: I have no links but from experience that's what happens. split the query step by steps and see where it brakes.

Comment: Code sample for what you mean maybe?